# Git repository server GIT_PROJECT_ROOT

Tags: apache-httpd, git

I'm trying to configure my own git repository server with Git SmartHTTP and Apache2. So followed [these](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) instuctions from the official git manual. But during the configuration it becomes not clear to me, what the `GIT_PROJECT_ROOT` variable exactly configures: Does it set the path to exactly one repository on a webserver or can you set it's value to a folder path which contains all your repositories.
And what other things does this variable affects?
The problem is that there is no description or explanation in the official git manual neither in the SmartHTTP chapter nor in the environment variables chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a description in the [git-http-backend manual](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html). 
Variable `GIT_PROJECT_ROOT` is set to a parent path of all repositories and similar to the Apache [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/urlmapping.html#documentroot) directive, it is used to translate an URL-path to the filesystem:

> ### URL TRANSLATION
>
> To determine the location of the repository on disk, *git http-backend* concatenates the environment variables `PATH_INFO`, which is set automatically by the web server, and `GIT_PROJECT_ROOT`, which must be set manually in the web server configuration. If `GIT_PROJECT_ROOT` is not set, *git http-backend* reads `PATH_TRANSLATED`, which is also set automatically by the web server.
>
> ### EXAMPLES
>
> All of the following examples map `http://$hostname/git/foo/bar.git` to `/var/www/git/foo/bar.git`.
>
> Apache 2.x
>
> Ensure mod_cgi, mod_alias, and mod_env are enabled, set `GIT_PROJECT_ROOT` (or DocumentRoot) appropriately, and create a ScriptAlias to the CGI:
>
> ```
> SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
> SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
> ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
> ```

So the `/git/` part in `http://hostname/git/foo/bar.git` is mapped to the git-http-backend CGI script and the remaining part `foo/bar.git` is appended to the path of the `GIT_PROJECT_ROOT` (or DocumentRoot) variable which should match a Git repo.

Comment: So if I get it right, an incoming request to the webserver just reaches the `http://hostname/git` part of the url and the `foo/bar.git` part (which resides inside the `PATH_INFO` variable) is combined with the `GIT_PROJECT_ROOT` to access the repository itself. And secondly, is this the reason why the webserver returns a 404 error if you're trying to access the `http://hostname/git/` folder in your webbrowser?

Comment: (1) Yes and (2) I would guess that depends on your Apache configuration, i.e. if it finds an index.html, index.php or whatever (see [DirectoryIndex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)) 
or if directory listings are allowed ([Options Indexes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options)).
Look into your Apache error.log if there is more information.

Comment: The problem occured because of my Apache2 configuration: The `ScriptAlias` setting had the same url path (`/repos/git`) as the repositories on the local filesystem (`DocumentRoot /repos/git`). So if you call `http://hostname/git` the webserver passed the request always to the CGI script instead of serving the files to the webbrowser. Setting `ScriptRoot` to a fictive path (`/git/`) and let the repos reside in `/repos/git` solved it.